# asp.net c# textbox outside update panel but inside an hidden panel is not updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, updatepanel, panel

I got a `gridview` inside an update panel with `UpdateMode="Conditional"` that is firing a `SelectIndexChanged` on each click on the rows filling a bunch of labels and a TextBox that are inside an hidden panel (connected to a ModalPopupExtender).

When I call the **.Show** for the `ModalPopupExtender` I was expecting to see the labels filled and the textbox with the data I fetched from the oracle blob but everything is empty.

If I check the **.text** property of the textbox is correctly filled as I expect but is not rendered when I call for the show. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is hidden panel also inside update panel?

Comment: No it is not. It's outside of the Update Panel.

Answer (score 0):

If ModalPopupExtender is inside UpdatePanel then the data will not be available unless you update the update panel.
Try calling `Update()` method of UpdatePanel control and data should be displayed.

If ModalPopupExtender is not inside UpdatePanel, then move it inside update panel and call `Update()` method

Comment: I'll give a try but in this way I'll force the postback of the gridview don't I?